# DataGridView adjusting Height with scroll bars

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, scrollbar

I have a datagrid view that has a full height of .height=500. If client click on a button, I need to change the height of the data grid view because I need to display a groupbox with a few textboxes and comboboxes. I am able to do that with...

```
datagridview1.height=150
```

What my problem is - if I first populate the datagrid with lets say 20 rows of data, and then I edit the height, I am not able to scroll down the grid to see clients that were cut off by my height adjustment. So I tried something like this....

```
datagridview1.ScrollBars = Windows.Forms.ScrollBars.Horizontal
```

But it's the same thing. No scorll bars for this datagridview.

Comment: Don't you want `Vertical` rather than `Horizontal`?

Comment: If you resize the control, it should automatically add the needed scrollbars as needed when `ScrollBars = Both`

Comment: Duhhh jinx its been a long week

Comment: If I select the 15th or w/e item from the grid, and then it gets adjusted (at which point I can't see the selection), is it possible for me to move it so that i can be seen in the grid